# Can VLC play Blu-ray films?

Tags: vlc-media-player, blu-ray

I just tried to play a Blu-ray disc and VLC says `Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'dvd://E:\'. Check the log for details`.

I have a disc in the drive!

- Will it not play because my monitor is in 4:3 view or something?
- What can can I use to play it?
- Any simple programs?
- Any quality software I can use now?  Or is everything paidware?

I have an LG drive on an HP computer using Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried [BS Player](http://www.bsplayer.com/bsplayer-english/products/bsplayer.html)? It does have a neat feature that when enabled it remembers last position of a video file.

Comment: Is it free without ads etc.?

Comment: You can get free version and this [comparison](http://www.bsplayer.com/bsplayer-english/download.html) shows what you get for free.

Comment: If VLC can't play it there is something wrong. VLC can play almost everything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes VLC can play Blu-ray discs.

You will need to update the **keys database** and **AACS dynamic library**, both of which can be downloaded from http://vlc-bluray.whoknowsmy.name/.

Comment: Will just updating to the latest VLC version work?

Comment: That could work too, since they have just release some new updates for version 2

Comment: @Salmonerd I couldn't find the **%APPDATA%/aacs/** folder?

Comment: @RogUE You need to make it yourself

Comment: anyone know if this is legal?

Comment: @D.Tate In which country? Personally I'm more concerned about right and wrong than legal technicalities, especially when it comes to copyright laws (they're a bit ludicrous in many places thanks to corruption). Do you think it's fair that you should be allowed to play blu-rays you have legitimately bought and paid for? I certainly do.

Comment: @MGOwen It's a frustrating issue no doubt. Sounds like you (and me, for the record) understand that there are multiple factors to this. But I am with you.... understanding if something is truly right ... or truly moral... is better than only knowing if it's "legal". Gotta start somewhere though, and laws are theoretically made for some good purpose.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. After following these steps, I still end up with the `VLC is unable to open the MRL 'bluray:///E:/'`

Comment: To add some context -- from what I can tell, this "keys database" contains a number of keys from a certain set of titles up to whenever the database is most recently updated (Mar 25 2018 as of this comment), and those titles seem to be popular TV shows and movies. In other words, if you are trying to watch a new show/movie or a relatively unknown title, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

For legal reasons, AACS and BD+ DRM libraries and keys are not shipped in VLC. However, by doing some tricks, VLC can play Blu-Ray movies.

How to Play Blu-Ray with VLC in Windows 8/Windows 7 64-bit/32-bit:
http://www.techisky.com/how-to/play-blu-ray-with-vlc-media-player-in-windows8.html

Comment: A summary of the link, please? It might break at any time...

Answer (score -1):

I also met this problem before and find the answer later, which is because VLC can only support part of Blu-ray discs(non-commercial). It can do nothing to the AACS and BD+ protected BDs. So you need install a professional Blu-ray player on your PC. I have a small tool here http://www.macblurayplayer.com/how-to-use-blu-ray-player-on-win7.htm

Hope it helps.